# How to create angular form with input fields for object type

Tags: angular, forms, post

I am a new learner in angular. I want to create a form that takes user input in the following way.
[image: request-post].
For this purpose, I created a class with following variables

```
export class Hotels {
   
    name: string;
    email: string;
    address1: string;
    address2: string;
    bookingList: Contract[];
}
```

The Contract is another model class with its respective attributes.

```
export class Contract {
    start_date: string;
    end_date: string;
   
}
```

The frontend HTML form looks like below,

```
<form (ngSubmit) = "saveHotel()">

    <input type="text" name = "name" [(ngModel)]=" hotel.name" placeholder="Enter hotel name"/>
    <input type="text" name = "email" [(ngModel)]=" hotel.email" placeholder="Enter hotel email"/>
    <input type="text" name = "address1" [(ngModel)]=" hotel.address1" placeholder="Enter hotel address line 1"/>
    <input type="text" name = "address2" [(ngModel)]=" hotel.address2" placeholder="Enter hotel address line 2"/>
    <input type="text" name = "address2" [(ngModel)]=" hotel.bookingList.start_date" placeholder="Enter hotel address line 2"/>
    <input type="text" name = "address2" [(ngModel)]=" hotel.bookingList.end_date" placeholder="Enter hotel address line 2"/>

    <button type="submit">Add Hotel</button>
</form>
```

However this wasn't successful as it shows the below error
[image: error]

Component file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Hotels } from 'src/app/models/hotels';
import { HotelsService } from 'src/app/services/hotels.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-hotels',
  templateUrl: './add-hotels.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-hotels.component.css']
})
export class AddHotelsComponent implements OnInit {
  hotel : Hotels = new Hotels();
  constructor(private _hotelService : HotelsService,
    private _router:Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  saveHotel(){
    this._hotelService.saveHotels(this.hotel).subscribe(
      data =>{
        console.log('response', data)
        this._router.navigateByUrl("/hotels");//to navigate back to main hotels pahge
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Services file

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Hotels } from '../models/hotels';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HotelsService {

  //to store http endpoint
  private getUrl: string = "http://localhost:8080/get/hotels";

  private postUrl: string = "http://localhost:8080/savehotel";
  constructor(private _httpClient:HttpClient) {  }

  getHotels(): Observable<Hotels[]>{
    return this._httpClient.get<Hotels[]>(this.getUrl).pipe(
      map(response => response)
    )
  }

  saveHotels(hotels: Hotels): Observable<Hotels> {
    return this._httpClient.post<Hotels>(this.postUrl, hotels);//no need to map as we just have to return the posted value back to component
  }
}
```

Comment: Your bookingList is an array, not an object. So you can't do this: `hotel.bookingList.end_date`. The solutions is maybe you can loop `let booking of bookingList` of your bookingList first and you can accessIt, maybe like: `booking.end_date`.

Answer (score 0):

In Hotels class, bookingList is an array so you can't access it like

hotel.bookingList.end_date

You have to loop over bookingList array and access end_date.

```
<

form (ngSubmit) = "saveHotel()">
    
  <input type="text" name = "name" [(ngModel)]=" hotel.name" placeholder="Enter hotel name"/>
  <input type="text" name = "email" [(ngModel)]=" hotel.email" placeholder="Enter hotel email"/>
  <input type="text" name = "address1" [(ngModel)]=" hotel.address1" placeholder="Enter hotel address line 1"/>
  <input type="text" name = "address2" [(ngModel)]=" hotel.address2" placeholder="Enter hotel address line 2"/>
  <span *ngFor="let booking of  hotel.bookingList">
    <input type="text" name = "address2" [(ngModel)]=" booking.start_date" placeholder="Enter hotel address line 2"/>
    <input type="text" name = "address2" [(ngModel)]=" booking.end_date" placeholder="Enter hotel address line 2"/>
  </span>
      
  <button type="submit">Add Hotel</button>
</form>
```

If you want to dynamically add booking to hotel. You can have a separate button to add booking to hotel.bookingList array.

```
<button type="submit" (click)="addHotelBooking()">Reset</button>
    
addHotelBooking = () => {
        this.hotel.bookingList.push({
          start_date: null,
          end_date: null 
        })
}
```

Comment: can you provide me an example of doing it please

Comment: i have edited the answer. it will be one of the way to handle array of objects data.

Comment: Thanks alot for the reply. But I encountered a small problem, where the input fields with the span is not getting displayed in the UI. Do you know the reason for this?

Comment: You should have atleast one booking inside hotel.bookingList array.

Comment: no, like the input field which is within the <span> tag , itself is not getting displayed in the form

Comment: Yeah. Because we have a for loop in span. Only  if we have something to iterate over. it will display.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239866/discussion-between-mystica-and-shashikamal-r-c).